# Web.config transformation with website project,MSBuild and MS Release Management

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, ms-release-management

I am trying to release my "website project" using MSBuild and MS Release Management.

Config transform needs to be done based on the environment.  As you may know, in "website project", we cannot simply "right click" and add "config Transform". So I have added the config transform file by creating a new publish profile  named "Release" and right click on the "Release.pubxml"> Add Config Transform. Web.Release.config has been created under web.config. I have made necessary changes and verified "Preview Transform".

Publish profile has been specified as MSBuild Argument(/p:PublishProfile=Release) in the release template.

My problem  is, web.config transformation is not happening with my Build. I have verified it in the drop location. Along with web.config file, Web.Release.config is also coming in the drop location...!

Please guide me.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use config transforms with Release Management. RM is based on the concept of "build once, deploy many". Config transforms are based on the configuration you're building, which is "build once, deploy once". It's fundamentally incompatible.

The correct approach is to create an alternate, tokenized web.config called web.config.token. This file can contain tokens, like `__Foo__` (note the double underscores on either side).

Then, build with the Release Default Template (available under the RM client installation folder), which will swap the tokenized web.config file in.

In your Component in RM, under the "Configuration Variables" section, define your tokens.

When you use the Component in a Release Template, you can choose the values that will be inserted in the config file in place of the tokens.

Comment: @GiulioVian That's not a bad alternative, but the preference (IMHO) would be to take advantage of the tool's native functionality whenever possible. It might, of course, be that one environment's config files are wildly different from another's, rendering tokenization impossible. That's a whole different discussion, though. :)

Comment: @DanielMann i am trying the same thing. My transformed web.config will have tokens and that will be replaced in the RM Component. But this transformation is not happening and token are not geting created with MSBuild...!

Comment: If I create web.config.token manually, will it pickup during the build?

Comment: @DanielMann Correct. It really depends on your scenario, if you can use a single platform from start to finish, great! If you still fight with a non-DevOps-throw-over-the-wall organization, a time proven tokenizer tool can rescue.

Comment: I would suggest reading Colin's blog post, describes how to do it perfectly http://www.colinsalmcorner.com/post/webdeploy-and-release-management--the-proper-way

Comment: You have to add the token file to your solution, manually.  Make a copy of your web.config file and save it as web.config.token.  Edit the token file and replaces the value(s) you wish to replace with the token name (__tokenName__).  Change the properties of the token file to always copy it to the output directory.  Your release management component that does the deploy must be configured to process the tokens.  Remember - token names are case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

These links should help.

Using xml transform to get your tokenized config file is better for maintainability.

- http://www.colinsalmcorner.com/post/webdeploy-and-release-management--the-proper-way
- http://incyclesoftware.zendesk.com/entries/21448302
- http://incyclesoftware.zendesk.com/entries/21487316

Comment: I have done tokenization and parameterisation with "Web Application" type projects in VS. But both are not working for "Website" type project with MSBuild.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a page which describes all you need: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alming/archive/2015/01/19/using-web-config-transformations-and-release-manager.aspx

In few words:

1. Add MSBuild argument in build definition:
   `/p:UseWPP_CopyWebApplication=true /p:PipelineDependsOnBuild=false`
2. Add custom transformation config file, but use `__VariableName__` instead of actual values.
3. Set variable value in RM release template